# git permission error on a public repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control

When I do `git clone git@github.com:btholt/complete-intro-to-react.git`

I got error of

```
Cloning into 'complete-intro-to-react'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github is trying to authenticate you using your SSH public key, but its failing since they are not aware of it.

Fixing this is pretty easy.

Steps:

1. Create an account on Github => https://github.com/join
2. [Add an SSH key to your Github account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)

And you're done!

You should be able to clone any Github repo you want after this, as Github will be able to identify you using your public key.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the ssh URL to clone a repository,
it tries to authenticate you using your public key.
If this authentication fails, the cloning fails.

You can either get the public key authentication working,
or you could clone the repository using the https URL instead of ssh, that is:

```
git clone https://github.com/btholt/complete-intro-to-react
```

Comment: but I did have an account on github

Comment: The message you get is clearly an error message from SSH, not from Git. Perhaps you did not upload your public key on GitHub, or perhaps the command you ran used a different key than the one registered.

Comment: Having an account on GitHub is one thing, configuring it and especially your PC to use public key authentication is another. See their [help page](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) to fix that.